# Notification in Contact update when Contact is merged

Tags: trigger, merge

When contact is merged and assume winning contact is updated, is there a SFDC standard event that will tell us that "winning contact is updated as part of merge process NOT regular UI record update"? If not, what are the different ways that I can know in Update Contact Trigger that contact is updates as part of merge process?

Answer (score 1):

To reliably detect merge events, you'll need to implement an `after delete` trigger. Records in the `after delete` trigger will have a special field called `MasterRecordId` populated, which allows you to determine that they've been deleted due to a merge into the record whose Id is provided. This applies to all objects that support merges.

See [Triggers and Merge Statements](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_merge_statements.htm) for details on the order of operations that are performed during a merge. Update triggers are fired as they normally would be, but that doesn't provide you any information about the merge as such.

The way the documentation is written and your experience with static variables makes me think the merge is executed in two ordered transactions: first the Delete event is completely executed, then the Update event is executed in a separate transaction with no access to the merge details.

The only other option, if you don't want to do your processing in `after delete`, would be to write merge details to a custom object that you can later process asynchronously in a Queueable rather than a `before/after update` trigger

Comment: Hi @David Reed, from the given link, Update Trigger is fired after "After Delete", is there a way to know in Update Trigger that it was fired from "After Delete"? I tried Boolean Static Flag, making it TRUE at "After Delete" but when I read the same flag at "Update Trigger" then I get default value and not the set TRUE value, any thoughts? Thanks.